# Is it possible to create a Xamarin Custom Control that is a group of standard controls?

Tags: xamarin.forms, controls

Like back in the WebForm days you could create your own reusable User Control, or like a partial in MVC Razor.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.   See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview#create-a-custom-control

Comment: Thanks. Post as the answer and I will upvote.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create custom controls in Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59205587/how-to-create-custom-controls-in-xamarin)